# Number of cores seen by sensors

Tags: cpu, sensors

The system monitor shows 4 cores, while the output from the sensors contains info only for two cores. What is the reason of that? My cpu is Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3317U

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your processor is dual core. System monitor shows you the number of threads, which is 4 for your processor.

## Intel i5-3317U

[image]